# Should I use a VirtualStore solution on Vista?

Tags: c#

Because my application need to write settings in Program Files. So, please me choose a solution:
1. Should I use VirtualStore solution when use on Windows Vista & Windows 7?
2. Use manifest to run application with Administator mode.

See this topic: http://forums.techarena.in/vista-help/730258.htm

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks.

And if I use VirtualStore solution, how to know VirtualStore is being used & how to get the VirtualStore's path.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just fix the application and write a) to the user's directory or b) to the all users profile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're really that lazy and don't want to save the data to the user's application data directory *where it belongs*, you need to enable virtualization for the process, and then you can write to Program Files while Windows handles the rest.

- Get a handle to your process token using OpenProcessToken.
- Enable virtualization for the token by calling SetTokenInformation with TokenVirtualizationEnabled.